# Embed static HTML page in play 2.2.1

Tags: java, html, css, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to display a static html page embedded into a `play 2.2.1` project.

I have created a `play 2.2.1` project.

I have put my whole static html files with its assets(js, css, img ect.) into the public folder of play.

[image]

I also have deleted the precreated `controller` and `views packages`.

My routing file looks the following:

```
GET  /comingSoon.html   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="comingSoon.html")
```

However, when I go to `http://localhost:9000/` I get:

[image]

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, I don't get it, actually Play told you that you didn't create any route for path `/` ;)

just add this route:

```
GET   /   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="comingSoon.html")
```

Comment: thx you very much for your answer! It works ;) however, my stylepaths do not work `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">` do I need them to be integrated into a scala format, even though they are in the public folder?

Comment: Sorry, in comments there's not too much place for samples, so maybe create new question and show us which routes have you declared and where exactly do you keep the bootstrap bundle.